# Fitting table into page while not ruining the caption

Tags: tables

I have to fit this table into a page. Using `adjustcode` failed since it made the caption stuck onto first cell of the table instead of spanning on top of table.

The paper is double column so I'm using `\begin{table*}` instead of `\begin{table}` to fill the table into 2 columns.

`\processtable` serves as a title for the table.

`\botrule`, `\midrule` and `\toprule` are linedrawing commands.

Currently output looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ4ln.jpg

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
.
.
.
\begin{table*}[ht]
\processtable{Some of the works with their contributions to the field and their recognition rates\label{tbl:0}}
{\begin{tabular*}{20pc}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll@{}}\toprule
Method    & Contribution    & Recognition Rate \\ 
\midrule
Lopes et. al.  & Generating synthetic samples to broaden the database for CNN learning process & 98.92  \\ 
BDBN & A set of weak classifiers that each is responsible for classifying one expression.  & 96.70  \\ 
AUDP  & Decomposing a facial expression into Micro-Action-Patterns and grouping them for higher level representation & 93.70  \\
Fan \& Tjahjadi  & spatial–temporal framework based on histogram of gradients and optical flow & 83.70  \\
Zhong et. al.  & two-stage multi-task sparse learning (MTSL) framework to efficiently locate the discriminative patches that discloses the expressions  & 93.30  \\
Liu et. al.  & manifold modeling of videos based on a proposed mid-level representation, i.e. expressionlet & 94.19  \\
Gu et. al. & A radial encoding strategy for efficiently downsampling Gabor filter outputs and a new classifier combination method by extracting information from local classifiers. & 91.51  \\
Proposed & asdsa & 99 \\
\botrule
\end{tabular*}}{}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: please always provide a small complete document that shows the problem. `\processtable` and `\botrule` are not standard commands, I can guess `\botrule` but have no idea about `\processtable`

Comment: but you could just use a normal `tabular` but you should be using `p` columns (which allow line breaking) not `l` columns (which do not)

Comment: Please add a _compilable_ code. Your code is still not compilable

Comment: If you are using the class from http://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_Author-doublecolumn-submission.zip please say so, and provide a usable test file that demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you're using the documentclass indicated by David in his comment, you can solve your problem with a `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[ht]
\processtable{Some of the works with their contributions to the field and their recognition rates\label{tbl:0}}
{\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lXl@{}}\toprule
Method    & Contribution    & Recognition Rate \\ 
\midrule
Lopes et. al.  & Generating synthetic samples to broaden the database for CNN learning process & 98.92  \\ 
BDBN & A set of weak classifiers that each is responsible for classifying one expression.  & 96.70  \\ 
AUDP  & Decomposing a facial expression into Micro-Action-Patterns and grouping them for higher level representation & 93.70  \\
Fan \& Tjahjadi  & spatial–temporal framework based on histogram of gradients and optical flow & 83.70  \\
Zhong et. al.  & two-stage multi-task sparse learning (MTSL) framework to efficiently locate the discriminative patches that discloses the expressions  & 93.30  \\
Liu et. al.  & manifold modeling of videos based on a proposed mid-level representation, i.e. expressionlet & 94.19  \\
Gu et. al. & A radial encoding strategy for efficiently downsampling Gabor filter outputs and a new classifier combination method by extracting information from local classifiers. & 91.51  \\
Proposed & asdsa & 99 \\
\botrule
\end{tabularx}}{}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]